# intellisense turning off in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm working on an ASP web app project in VS 2012. My problem is that after some time intellisense stops working in certain files, and not even CTRL-space pops it up. When I restart VS it works again. Any suggestions?

Comment: File a bug report for MS... Happens to me as well time to time.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your .suo file? Had a similar issue a while back.